# Is possible to set load time of the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a website loader in GIF format but it doesn't appear because of website is loaded in 0.001 seconds. Is there possible to set load website to 2 seconds to loader animation is visible?

Comment: I can give you a simple example using `delay()`

Comment: you can use `setTimeout`, can u share the code you are using?

Comment: This is usually accomplished by adding ads and tracking code. Yes, I'm sorry, I respectfully dismiss.

Answer (score 3):

I made you an example of a preloader using the `delay()` method (2 sec = 2000), wrapped inside the load event.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.animation').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
.animation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="animation">
  <img src="https://flevix.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Spin-Preloader.gif">
</div>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsa inventore, deleniti excepturi porro dicta, doloribus quisquam sequi quod ab reprehenderit assumenda? Voluptatibus accusantium aliquam magnam. Praesentium dolore, possimus blanditiis perferendis.
</div>
```